# Sometimes API is taking too long to load

Tags: node.js, angular

```
@action('Get District')
  async getDistrict(districtId: number, current = false): Promise<IDistrictInfo> {
    this._adminStore.adminDistrictDetailsStore.setLoading(true);

    try {
      let district;
      if (current) {
        district = await this._http.get<IDistrictInfo>(`${environment.urls.api}/districts/${districtId}/current`).toPromise();
      } else {
        district = await this._http.get<IDistrictInfo>(`${environment.urls.api}/districts/${districtId}`).toPromise();
      }
      console.log("district", district, current)

      await this.getSchools(districtId);
      await this.getDistrictPendingCovidData(districtId);

      applyTransaction(() => {
        this._adminStore.adminDistrictDetailsStore.setError(null);
        this._adminStore.adminDistrictDetailsStore.setLoading(false);
        this._adminStore.adminDistrictDetailsStore.update({ district });
      });

      return district;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      applyTransaction(() => {
        this._adminStore.adminDistrictDetailsStore.setError(e.message);
        this._adminStore.adminDistrictDetailsStore.setLoading(false);
      });
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: please add some context to your question. Mention which api is taking long time to load. And where are you facing problem. What each API call is doing etc.

Comment: Use postman https://www.postman.com/ to test api. If postman always comes with a similar response time. Then the problem could be another place.  If you are using a shared server response time could be varied due to the traffic. In that case test your code in different server.

Comment: We have several counties, each county has districtId, when I select a particular county, it will navigate to the school information which is this service "/current`)". once this service has passed we can see the school information, This service is taking too long for only one of the counties and in Other counties, it was going through within 2,3 sec. Sometimes it's failing because it's taking too long to load.